# How to split layout based on screen size? (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css

I have create some font awesome icons on my website and I have made them responsive by changing the font size in the CSS.

Desktop View:

[image]

Mobile View:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="icons">
<span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
  <i class="far fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-hammer fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
<span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
  <i class="far fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-wrench fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
<span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
  <i class="far fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-clipboard fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
<span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
  <i class="far fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-paint-roller fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
<span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
  <i class="far fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-screwdriver fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
<span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
  <i class="far fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-border-none fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.icon-background {
    color: #000000;
}

.icons{
    text-align:center;
}

.fa-stack{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 4vw;
    }

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

.fa-stack{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-size: 10vw;
    }
    
}
```

So visually they look fine as I expected. But there is one issue. I am thinking that may approach is not solid. Every device has different sizes and I kind of feel that there is no gaurantee that the icons will be displayed in two rows of three in every mobile view or it will remain in one line of six on desktop view.

So what I was thinking and this is my question, is there a way to state if a screen is more that 768px, to display in a single line, else if it's smaller then split the icons so they show as two rows of three?

Comment: Have you considered using a grid, having a set size of icon maybe, and letting the system sort out how many icons it can fit in a row?

Comment: @AHaworth Hmmmm... don't really know much about a grid. I will do some research on this. If you have an idea on how it works then happy to see your answer.

Comment: It just seemed simpler than having to learn about and load a new framework/library if you aren't already using one. Will put up a snippet shortly.

Comment: Cool, I should also say that I am using wordpress and the code above is custom HTML I have added into the wordpress, so it's already responsive with bootstrap enabled

Comment: Hi, in that case if you already have bootstrap then the answers already here seem sensible - use that and it works out the grid-type layouts for you for different sizes based on a 12-column approach.

Comment: Ok, will give it a go, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to write CSS for each screen resolution. or use bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You should use bootstrap responsive layout system to endup your nightmares(write css for each media screen size). it will do this job.

[Bootstrap responsive icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853182/bootstrap-responsive-icons)